# Как создать обученную модель tensorflow для android?

Tags: android, model, tensorflow

Создаю модель для новых категорий -> https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

При использовании созданной модели в android (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) новая модель не инициализируется и не работает.

Comment: Работает ли модель на компьютере? Пробовали запускать? Возможно, имена входов/выходов другие? Или формат? Можете привести логи из приложения для Android?